# Cubism - value for selected time and row

Tags: css, graph, d3.js, cubism.js

I love [Cubism.js](http://square.github.com/cubism/)

But i want to implement a feature i am missing from the demo.

And that is the need to see the **value for a selected time and row**.
When i have a mouse-over on the graph - i would like to show the value for the row the mouse cursor is on (see picture beside the vertical line)

[image: value shown for the time and row]
How could this be done?

Do i have a chance with CSS or do i need to dig into [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) ?

**edit**: i have found the [Stock-Demo](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html) ... but still now clue how this is done :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve that easily by playing with the CSS. First, hide all values:

```
.horizon .value {display: none;}
```

Then show values on hover:

```
.horizon:hover .value {display: inherit;}
```

Comment: The left and right keyboard keys also seem to move the line, but I'll leave that one to you `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Check out view-source:http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html. What you need is the following:
`d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "rule")
  .call(context.rule());`

This uses context.rule() to accomplish that, a d3/cubism function.

The previous answer give you the value of one row, the row the mouse is on. The cubism.js rule will give value of all rows.